# Excel - Combining same names in 3 different sheets and adding their values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

This is a project in school, sorry I just have a basic `VLOOKUP` knowledge in Excel. I have three sheets named: pasta, pastries and cakes. So basically this is a tally of how much we sell, and on the 4th sheet, we must list the TOTAL payment each person ordered from each of the 3 products above.

[image: Snapshot of all the sheets]

so in the images, those 3 sheets are the total payment each person must pay on each product. If you notice, there are duplicate names within the SAME SHEET and WITHIN THE 3 SHEETS. Like Joey's name appears twice on the pastries sheet, and once in the cakes sheet.

So basically i think you're getting my drift, I want in sheet 4 to appear all the payments joey must make in all three products. Basically determining/looking up all same names and adding all the values, then listing everyone else. The closest end I was able to achieve in consolidate was to create 3 more tables in sheet 4 with each product, `VLOOKUP` all info, create a 4th table in sheet 4, and do consolidation (see sheet 4). But the problem is other than the fact that it is such a mess, they do get consolidated, but only after the consolidate program is entered. But if another input was made in the other 3 sheets, lets say joey buy 3 more pastas, it does not update anymore. Clicking create links in consolidation puts out an error.

I tried searching on youtube  and forums stating the way of "Consolidate", but it always either messes up the whole sheet, adds a column in between, and other stuff. So I may want to do this in `VLOOKUP` way, so that it can be dynamic, meaning that the consolidation changes automatically EACH TIME an input is made/changed. And it is much cleaner, as I do not have to create 3 more tables in sheet 4 to show the summary of each product.

Comment: I don't understand how sheet 4 is derived from sheets 1:3.  For example, in sheet 4 Joey appears as you describe above; but he does not appear that way (nor have the same numbers) in sheets 1:3.  I suggest you look at `SUMIF` for your solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

Consolidating  names from individual sheets is not done in a straightforward way with formulae. You have to resort to VBA for that, which I assume is not in the scope of your project.

However, assuming that in sheet 4, you have all names lined up in the first column, the summation is easily done with SUMIF.

If this is your source sheet

[image]

In your new sheet, line up all names on column A, preferably sorted.

Add a column for each food item, say Pasta, Pastries.

Use this formula in each row.

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!A2:A7,Sheet2!A3,Sheet1!B2:B7)
```

First column above Sheet1!A2:A7 is the list of names. Sheet2!A3 is the current name in question. Sheet1!B2:B7 is the amount due.

This would total each food item under that person. Finally you can have a total column to give the total across all food items. If needed hide the individual food totals. So finally, you might have something like below. Hide columns B and C in the end, if needed.

[image]